# SLURM sbatch fails while interactive srun succeeds (PyTorch distributed run)

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, slurm, multi-gpu

I have a python script that test connectivity in the `torch.distributed.run` environment.
Allocating nodes and running the command by hand results in a successfuly execution.

Running an sbatch script results in a timeout and no execution at all.

Python Script:

```py
import os
import socket

import torch
import torch.distributed as dist

socket.AF_INET6 = socket.AF_INET
print("Starting python script")


local_rank = int(os.environ["LOCAL_RANK"])
torch.cuda.set_device(local_rank)
device = torch.device("cuda", local_rank)
hostname = socket.gethostname()

gpu = f"[{hostname}-{local_rank}]"

try:
    # test distributed
    dist.init_process_group("nccl")
    dist.all_reduce(torch.ones(1).to(device), op=dist.ReduceOp.SUM)
    dist.barrier()

    # test cuda is available and can allocate memorys
    torch.cuda.is_available()
    torch.ones(1).cuda(local_rank)

    # global rank
    rank = dist.get_rank()
    world_size = dist.get_world_size()

    print(f"{gpu} is OK (global rank: {rank}/{world_size})")

    dist.barrier()
    if rank == 0:
        print(f"pt={torch.__version__}, cuda={torch.version.cuda}, nccl={torch.cuda.nccl.version()}")

except Exception:
    print(f"{gpu} is broken")
    raise
```

SLURM SBATCH file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=rtx-distribution-test        # name
#SBATCH --nodes=2                               # nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1                     # crucial - only 1 task per dist per node!
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4                       # number of cores per tasks
#SBATCH --partition=clara       
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:rtx2080ti:1                  # number of gpus
#SBATCH --time 01:15:00                         # maximum execution time (HH:MM:SS)
#SBATCH --output=clara_rtx/%x-%j.out            # output file name
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL

# load modules
module load Python
srun pip install --user -r requirements.txt

MASTER_PORT=12340
MASTER_ADDR=$(scontrol show hostnames "$SLURM_JOB_NODELIST" | head -n 1)
echo "MASTER_ADDR="$MASTER_ADDR

GPUS_PER_NODE=1

export NCCL_DEBUG=INFO
LOGLEVEL=INFO

srun bash -c "NCCL_DEBUG=INFO python -m torch.distributed.run --nproc_per_node $GPUS_PER_NODE --nnodes $SLURM_NNODES --node_rank $SLURM_PROCID --master_addr $MASTER_ADDR --master_port $MASTER_PORT torch-distributed-gpu-test_no_flock.py"
```

Interactive Run Command:

```bash
 srun bash -c 'NCCL_DEBUG=INFO python -m torch.distributed.run --nproc_per_node 1 --nnodes 2 --node_rank $SLURM_PROCID --master_addr clara06 --master_port 12340 torch-distributed-gpu-test_no_flock.py'
```

Output of Interactive Command:

```
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:426] [c10d] The server socket cannot be initialized on [::]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
Starting python script
Starting python script
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
clara06:3883842:3883842 [0] NCCL INFO Bootstrap : Using ib0:10.10.10.6<0>
clara06:3883842:3883842 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin : No plugin found (libnccl-net.so), using internal implementation
clara06:3883842:3883842 [0] NCCL INFO cudaDriverVersion 11060
NCCL version 2.14.3+cuda11.7
...
```

Output of SBATCH script:

```
[W socket.cpp:426] [c10d] The server socket cannot be initialized on [::]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [clara06.CENSORED]:12340 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 3111195.1 ON clara23 CANCELLED AT --- DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 3111195 ON clara23 CANCELLED AT --- DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

If run long enough (by increasing the time limit), the job will cancel with a `RuntimeError: Socket Timeout` with the following stack trace:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/software/all/staging/Python/3.10.8-GCCcore-12.2.0/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/software/all/staging/Python/3.10.8-GCCcore-12.2.0/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 798, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 346, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 794, in main
    run(args)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 785, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 134, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 241, in launch_agent
    result = agent.run()
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/metrics/api.py", line 129, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 723, in run
    result = self._invoke_run(role)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 858, in _invoke_run
    self._initialize_workers(self._worker_group)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/metrics/api.py", line 129, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 692, in _initialize_workers
    self._rendezvous(worker_group)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/metrics/api.py", line 129, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 549, in _rendezvous
    workers = self._assign_worker_ranks(store, group_rank, group_world_size, spec)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/metrics/api.py", line 129, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 624, in _assign_worker_ranks
    role_infos = self._share_and_gather(store, group_rank, group_world_size, spec)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 661, in _share_and_gather
    role_infos_bytes = store_util.synchronize(
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/utils/store.py", line 64, in synchronize
    agent_data = get_all(store, rank, key_prefix, world_size)
  File "/home/CENSORED/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/utils/store.py", line 34, in get_all
    data = store.get(f"{prefix}{idx}")
RuntimeError: Socket Timeout
```

The interactive srun takes around 2 seconds to completion while the sbatch timeouts after 15 minutes.

- I have tried different srun commands using `torchrun` and `torch.distributed.launch`.
- I also replaced the `"` with `'` in the srun command inside the sbatch script.
- I have tried different configuations with v100 gpus and more gpus per node
- I have added the `--jobid` to the srun command with no difference

Comment: nop, still unsolved. The IT of the cloud provider also couldn't figure out why. I assume it's a location specific issue